# Positioning drawn shape in HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I have a complex shape that's been generated from an SVG file that we're clipping images to in canvas.

However, all of the bezier curve coordinates are based on 0,0. Our shape's size scales depending on the size of the canvas (which scales based on the user's screen width).

Is there a way to take the shape that's already been drawn and then move it to a certain position on the canvas? Much like ctx.scale(#, #) will scale the drawn shape?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ctx.translate()` to change the position of items on your canvas.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#Translating

Using translate will alter the position of everything that is subsequently drawn on the canvas.  If you just want to move one thing, you can either do:

```
ctx.translate(x,y);
// draw something
ctx.translate(-x,-y);
```

or you can do:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x,y);
// draw something
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That worked like a charm (brand new to canvas, can you tell?)